# Unity Project not loading up

Tags: unity-game-engine

A couple of hours ago I turned off my computer and I just recently came back to work on my project
and this has been stuck on my screen for hours

[image]

I tried restarting my computer that didn't work and I tried to reopen the project like 10 times and it just stays stuck on ("Initialize Asset Database")

Comment: Zip your project as a backup, try delete Library folder, re-open, see if it helps.

Comment: Alternatively, use git to commit your work, upgrade Unity version and see if it helps.

Comment: @aybe tried both methods still doesn't work

Comment: Find the Unity logs, delete them, open project again, check the logs to see where it chokes, do a web search about what you may have have found in it. https://forum.unity.com/threads/project-wont-open-from-unity-hub-after-upgrade-and-rename.898034/

Comment: @aybe Should it be loading the Player, Editor and Package Manager Log?

Comment: Check the editor log, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: At the end it Just Says ([Package Manager] Done registering packages in 0.21s seconds) but above that it doesn't look like there's a issue

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on on your side, myself I'd try on another environment, such as another computer or VM, or alternatively, ask in their forums.

Comment: **1)** Quit/terminate Unity **2)** Delete the **.\Library** folder  **3)** Run Unity **4)** Your **Library** folder is re-built and your project hopefully loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Solution

1. Do a backup of your Projects *(use Google Drive, Dropbox or Localstorage)*
2. Deinstall the complete Unity Hub with the version
3. Install the Unity Hub including your favorite version

Comment: i guess i can call myself a "it expert" now and can work in india from now on

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if the file name is wrong.
I made the mistake of putting the "\" character in the png file name. After renaming the file, the project loaded normally.